# IIR bandpass filter with very low corner frequencies

Tags: matlab, infinite-impulse-response

I'm trying to get in the MATLAB Signal Processing Toolbox a bandpass IIR filter having the following specifications: pass-band [0.1-0.5] Hz and stop-band attenuation 30 dB. I'm using the following command:
`[fdata,DigFilt] = bandpass(data, [0.1,0.5], fs, 'ImpulseResponse', 'iir', 'StopbandAttenuation', 30);`
The sampling frequency `fs` is 860 Hz. The command `info(DigFilt)` says that

> IIR Digital Filter (real)
>
> Number of Sections  : 5
> Stable              : Yes
> Linear Phase        : No
>
> Design Method Information
> Design Algorithm : Elliptic
>
> Design Options
> Match Exactly : both
>
> Design Specifications
> Sample Rate            : 860 Hz
> Response               : Bandpass
> Specification          : Fst1,Fp1,Fp2,Fst2,Ast1,Ap,Ast2
> Passband Ripple        : 0.1 dB
> First Stopband Edge    : 84.3 mHz
> Second Stopband Atten. : 30 dB
> Second Stopband Edge   : 67.9315 Hz
> Second Passband Edge   : 500 mHz
> First Passband Edge    : 100 mHz
> First Stopband Atten.  : 30 dB

The very strange parameter is Second Stopband Edge = 67.9315 Hz that seems to me too high considering the high corner frequency of 0.5 Hz. In fact, when i plot the frequency response with `fvtool(DigFilt)` i get the following

[image]

where i see that at 67.9315 Hz the attenuation is far below 30 dB. A zoom of the pass-band is the following

[image]

With this image, the first stop-band edge seems to be 57 mHz (and not 84.3 mHz as indicated by the command `info`) and the second stop-band edge seems to be 577 mHz. Why is there such disagreement between the images and the output of the command `info` ? Is it caused by the very low corner frequencies? Thanks to all.

Comment: Looks like your frequency grid for plotting is not dense enough. You can clearly see the individual frequency points and they look about 50m Hz apart.

Comment: Thanks, i will try a denser grid